# How to properly register my Wordpress widget using a PHP class

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins, widget

I've been learning how to create WP plugins and I can for the most part figure out the hooks to use and store input as options, use admin pages and user pages to collect the input.

I wanted to create a simple plugin to get the latest posts but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to put my register_widget call in order for the widget to show up so I can drag it to the sidebar of my choice.  It doesn't appear in the widget page at all.

The problem seems to be that I don't know where to put wp_register_widget or if I should be using register_widget ditto for wp_register_widget_control.  I believe the add_action at the bottom of the code is correct but nothing happens.  At one point I tried registering the widget below the add_action and it just showed the widget at the top of every page but still not on the drag and drop page.

I put the code in Pastebin since it was taking me forever to code block it http://pastebin.com/Q1nJHPV3

In the end I'd like to have a plugin that is widgetized so I can use it as a template for other plugins and a clear understanding of when and where things should be registered or actions set.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is use the Wordpress plugin "Plugin Options Starter Kit".  Has everything you need to get a Wordpress plugin up and running using options and settings API.